# AngularJS : Transcluding a child directive into a parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a newbie to Angular and have been trying small samples to learn the code.
Firstly, I would like to thank the brilliant solutions posted in stackoverflow.com.
Saved me so many hours so many times from needless debugging!

I'm building a simple expander collapse component. The code for which was available 
in an angular js ebook.

I've created a plunk for the same http://plnkr.co/edit/f2u32x2w0FJK1AzvVPEx?p=preview
The component works great. Except for the fact that in IE 8, i get the following error:

> *TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or methodundefined*

**The component renders fine. But there is this error that occurs along with it always.**

It turns out that the culprit is the line:

```
<expander class='expander' ng-repeat='expander in expanders' expander-title='expander.title'>{{expander.text}}</expander>
```

and specifically the part:

**{{expander.text}}**

Can some tell me what am I doing wrong here ? I'm just transcluding the content of the child directive into its template. Then I'm transcluding the child into the parent.
What is the issue here ? :(

Comment: Hey @Jim, somewhat unrelated problem, but the transclusion in your plunk is breaking when I switch to Angular version 1.2.x. I'm not sure what in [this changelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) broke it, but if you know and could let me know that'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your use of a custom HTML element (`<expander>`) which IE doesn't recognize. Either use the attribute notation on a supported element (e.g., `<div expander>...</div>`) or in JavaScript, create the element so IE will recognize it:

```
document.createElement('expander');
```

**References**

1. [AngularJS: Internet Explorer Compatibility](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: Hi Andre,

Thanks for the reply. 

The same link had mentioned to include the following if custom 
elements were being created:


    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script>
              var _e1= document.createElement('accordion');
              var _e2= document.createElement('expander');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->

I've done the same too.. But, I still get the error :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might consider to include "full blown" jQuery for IE8 just right before the Angular-script. 
This eliminates the error until the problem might be fixed in AJS/jQLite itself...

Remark: take only jQuery < 2.0, as 2.0+ are not IE8 compatible.

Comment: This is the best solution. Fixed MY exact same problem immediately. +1
`<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script>
      document.createElement('expander');
     </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->`